# Case insensitive search solr in Term query

Tags: solr

We want to make Term query in solr as case insensitive but it is not working.

http://localhost:8983/solr/terms?terms.fl=name&terms.fl=places&terms.prefix=Delhi

If we pass field like 'Delhi' it is not returning any result but 'delhi' is returning proper result. We use below to index and query our data.

```xml
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true"  omitNorms="true"> 
   <analyzer type="index">         
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100"/>
 </analyzer>  
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check that both name and places are of the type string_ci.
Could it also be the case that you forgot to reindex after adding a LowerCaseFilterFactory?

If it does not help, can you tell us if it is working with a regular query?